# PHP: timestamps between dates

Tags: php, arrays, date, timestamp

I have an array with timestamps. If this timestamps are between two given dates I need to collect them into another array.
Let me use an example:

Lets say $array1[] has:

```
Array ( [0] => 1299147500 [1] => 1299147453 [2] => 1299146476 [3] => 1299143220 [4] => 1297934349 [5] => 1297845742 [6] => 1297695551 [7] => 1296134251 [8] => 1295948452 [9] => 1295554308 [10] => 1295369389 [11] => 1295345559 [12] => 1295261432 [13] => 1295014784 [14] => 1294929846 [15] => 1294832875 )
```

I need to create $array2[] with those values from $array1[] that are between Thursday February 17, 2011 and Thursday March 3, 2011
How can I do this?

Thanks a ton

Comment: Use a `for` loop and check each element in `$array1` if it is between your desired dates, then add it to `$array2` if that is the case ? This should be quite basic, therefore I do not see what was causing trouble for you, or did I understand your question wrong ? To convert time specs like `Thursday February 17, 2011` to timestamps, use `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepad.org/mDvRJ534

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1299147500,1299147453,1299146476,1299143220,1297934349,1297845742,1297695551,1296134251,1295948452,1295554308,1295369389,1295345559,1295261432,1295014784,1294929846,1294832875);
$array2 = array();
$date1 = strtotime('Thursday February 17, 2011');
$date2 = strtotime('Thursday March 3, 2011');
foreach($array1 as $timestamp){
    if($timestamp <= $date2 && $timestamp >= $date1)
        $array2[] = $timestamp;
}
echo 'date1 = '.$date1."\n";
echo 'date2 = '.$date2."\n";
print_r($array2);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it may be it, but in the output, $array2[] contains timestamps that are lower than $date1. $date1 = 1297897200 and $array2: .. [2] => 1297695551
    [3] => 1296134251
    [4] => 1295948452 ...

Answer (score 2):

```
$low = strtotime('Thursday February 17, 2011');
$high = strtotime('Thursday March 3, 2011');

$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $timestamp) {
    if ($low <= $timestamp && $timestamp <= $high) {
        $array2[] = $timestamp;
    }
}
```

an alternative using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which will maintain the keys.

```
$low = strtotime('Thursday February 17, 2011');
$high = strtotime('Thursday March 3, 2011');

$array2 = array_filter($array1, function($timestamp) use ($low, $high) {
    return $low <= $timestamp && $timestamp <= $high;
});
```

Comment: I am 7 seconds too late... :-( +1 for you!

Comment: I have a feeling that this may be the right solution, but not the right way to teach someone solve a problem...

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert first and last date to timestamps using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
2. For each item in the array, if it is between min and max, copy it to the second array.
   Sort the array of timestamps

Comment: You're increasing the complexity by first sorting the timestamps. You can do it in O(n) with a single pass through the array.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this in another post over here mate [How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)