# If the date is between these two dates then

Tags: php

I have a `$bonus["from_date"]` and a `$bonus["to_date"]`, they are in this format: yyyy-mm-dd I would like to check that the todays date is between those two dates.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', time());
```

How can i do this?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$from = strtotime($bonus['from_date']);
$to = strtotime($bonus['to_date']);
$now = time();

if($from <= $now && $to >= $now) {
    // It's between
}
```

Comment: I could have swore there was a `between` keyword, but I guess I must be thinking of MySQL.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard comparison operators:

```
if ($today >= $bonus['from_date'] && $today <= $bonus['to_date'])
```

It works because you are storing as a string with biggest date elements first.