# How to check if a date is in a given range of day+month?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)

Having each year divided into periods such as

```
from 11-28 to 01-20
from 01-21 to 02-16
from 02-17 to 03-15
from 03-16 to 05-04
from 05-05 to 07-25
from 07-26 to 10-10
from 10-11 to 11-27
```

And some days as

```
$date1 = '06-09-1990';
$date2 = '05-03-1867';
$date3 = '02-29-1945';
$date4 = '06-24-2012';
$date5 = '12-25-2015';
$date6 = '07-15-2010';
```

How to check if a day is in one of these range?

P.S. Excuse me for my english

Comment: I think it's nota duplicate. The ranges have no "year" in this question so it's more difficult.

Comment: One solution: https://gist.github.com/borazslo/84819edbf4dea7a67e2e

Answer (score 4):

You can use this small function:

```
<?php
    $s_date = strtotime("2009-03-01 12:00");
    $e_date = strtotime("2009-03-03 14:00");
    $date = strtotime("2009-03-02 13:00");
    if($date > $s_date && $date < $e_date)
        print "Date is between start and end";
    else
        print "Date is outside start and end";
?>
```

---

### Another way

---

```
function isDateBetween($dt_start, $dt_check, $dt_end){
    if(strtotime($dt_check) > strtotime($dt_start) && strtotime($dt_check) < strtotime($dt_end))
        return true;
    return false;
}
isDateBetween("2004-01-01", "2004-01-02", "2004-01-03")
```

Comment: i need a method valid for any year, not for a specific one

Comment: What is specific here???

Comment: The algorithm must be valid for the same periods but for any year. With your method I have to insert a check for each year (obviously impossible).

Comment: I don't get what you said? It is valid for all the years. What kinda check you need to insert?

Comment: I have a certain day (e.g. 06/09/1990, 05/03/1867 etc...). I want to give this day to a period. The periods are the same for each year (e.g. from 03-15 to 04-05, from 04-06 to 04-20 etc. ...).

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, you can hardcode it in the function itself right? Just give `$dt_start = '06/09/1990'` and don't give the start and end dates. Or which ever you wanna omit.

Answer (score 2):

Date values in PHP are expressed as UNIX timestamps and they represent the number of seconds passed since January 1st 1970.

You can use `mktime` function to create the dates ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php ). 
Once you have them as numbers, you can easily compare them.

```
$interval_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2000);
$interval_end = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2010);
$my_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2004);
if($my_date > $interval_start && $my_date < $interval_end) {
    // in the interval
} else {
    // not in the interval
}
```

Comment: i need a method valid for any year, not for a specific one