# Check to see if current time is between a certain time in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, intervals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a date is in a given range of day+month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171447/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range-of-daymonth)

How would I go about checking to see if the current time is between two different time intervals?

Here's a practical example:
Let's say Dan is only around from 1PM - 4PM, how would I make a script to check to see if the current time is between 1PM and 4PM.  I want to use this to display a list of currently available rep's based on their schedule that's inputted into a database.

Comment: 1-4 on every day or on a specific day?

Answer (score 16):

use `H` from date - *24-hour format of an hour*:

```
if( (date('H') >= 13) && (date('H') < 16) ){
    // between 1PM and 4PM
}
```

Comment: Hey, just wondering what determines the time? Is it the user or the server time? Thanks

Comment: @Jordan PHP is server side so it cannot read client time.