# Check if date is in specific date range PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying this one out and it's been a while since I last coded in PHP.

I have a function that checks if given date is in between the range of dates:

```
pr($this->isDateBetween("2014-11-15", "2014-12-05", "2014-06-14"));

public function isDateBetween($dt_start, $dt_check, $dt_end){
        if(strtotime($dt_check) >= strtotime($dt_start) && strtotime($dt_check) <= strtotime($dt_end)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But seems like I'm getting `false`. The expected result should be `true` because `2014-12-05` is less than `2014-06-14` .

December is less than June so that should be true?

Also,
When I change `2014-06-14` to `2014-12-14` it became true.

Sorry, I'm not updated anymore with PHP. Please bear with me.

**EDITS**

Tried converting those to strtotime but still getting wrong results

Comment: You should probably find out which of the `dt_start` and `dt_end` is largest/smallest, then do an IF statement. The way you're doing it now, the order you've specified your arguments means no dates will be accepted. e.g. `2014-11-15` is your start date, but it is **after** `2015-06-14` which is your end date.

Comment: Additionally, the middle parameter i.e. the date you are checking is outside of the range specified by the other parameters.

Comment: Thanks I was confused. I need to study dates in a hard way but not thinking ahead

Comment: you are misusing your method :) just swap the dt_start and dt_end

Answer (score 0):

The solution exist here:

[How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)

**SOLUTION:**

Converting them to timestamps is the way to go alright, using strtotime, e.g.

```
$start_date = '2009-06-17';

$end_date = '2009-09-05';

$date_from_user = '2009-08-28';

check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user);


function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user)
{
  // Convert to timestamp
  $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
  $end_ts = strtotime($end_date);
  $user_ts = strtotime($date_from_user);

  // Check that user date is between start & end
  return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
}
```

Comment: That's right. OP's question seems to be a duplicate of your linked post.

Answer (score 0):

> The expected result should be true because 2014-12-05 is less than 2014-06-14 .

Totally wrong. The code **IS** Working. June 14th is "less" than December 12th. So your Dec 12th date is **NOT** between the start/end dates. it's past the end of the range.

Comment: I'm confused with the year end stuffs and thinking ahead. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

> The expected result should be true because 2014-12-05 is less than 2014-06-14 .

Absolutely not. The expected result is not `true`. It is `false`, because `"2014-12-05"` is not less than `"2014-06-14"`. December less than June? Never heard of such a peculiar logic before.

> Also, When I change 2014-06-14 to 2014-12-14 it became true.

That's right. Because `"2014-12-05"` is definitely less than `"2014-12-14"`, it is `true`. `5 December` is obviously smaller than `14 December`.

This has nothing to do with PHP versions or PHP built-in methods. This is all about your logic.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
pr($this->isDateBetween("2014-06-14", "2014-11-15", "2014-12-05"));

public function isDateBetween($dt_start, $dt_check, $dt_end){
        if(strtotime($dt_check) >= strtotime($dt_start) && strtotime($dt_check) <= strtotime($dt_end)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

This will return `true`.