# Categorize database rows by time

Tags: php, mysql

how can i categorize database rows by

> > today
> >
> > yesterday
> >
> > last 7 days
> >
> > last 30 days

Comment: What did you try? What is your data structure?

Comment: i will just get Datetime. I dont now how to use it after getting it. No need for  DB structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is in a given range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)

Comment: if you already have a Datetime object, you may want to take a look at the third highest answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9065661/5051310

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for checking post time:

```
$post_time1 = strtotime("05 December 2015");
$post_time2 = strtotime("02 December 2015");

check_post_time($post_time1);
check_post_time($post_time2);

function check_post_time($time) {
    $before_24 = strtotime("-1 day");
    $before_1week = strtotime("-1 week");
    $before_1month = strtotime("-1 month");
    if($time >= $before_24)
        echo "24hr ago";
    elseif($time >= $before_1week)
        echo "between 24hr - 1 week ago";
    elseif($time >= $before_1month)
        echo "between 7 days - 1 month ago";
    else
        echo "1 month ago";
}
```

Comment: sorry for late. when i write strotime("-1 week"), does it includes ("-1 day")? or, does ("-1 month") includes ("-1 week") and ("-1 day")?

Comment: strotime("-1 week") just gives the timestamp of day which is 7 days back from today.I am using if else ladder to find the range.

Comment: ("29 Nowember 2015") turns 1 month ago instead of  7 day-1 month ago

Comment: in your second elseif, `$time >= $time` is always true

Comment: Sorry for the typo it will be $before_1month

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Carbon PHP package](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) to display your time in human readable way. This package is very popular and it even included on the Laravel framework.

You can install the package using `Composer`. Once you installed this package you can use it by following like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

printf("Now: %s", Carbon::now());

// Human readable way
echo Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans(); // '2 minutes ago'
```