# How to check if a date is in a date range without comparing years?

Tags: php, date

As in the example i need to check if a date is include in a date range, the problem i just need to compare days and month not the year.
thanks

```
$start_date = '2009-06-17';

$end_date = '2009-09-05';

$date_from_user = '2009-08-28';

check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user);


function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user)
{
  // Convert to timestamp
  $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
  $end_ts = strtotime($end_date);
  $user_ts = strtotime($date_from_user);

  // Check that user date is between start & end
  return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
}
```

Comment: `month-day` are sortable if zero-filled on the day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)

Comment: for example, i just need to know if 21 nov is include or not  in the range 1 Nov / 31 jan, without the years...( 21/11 include in 1/11 - 31/01 ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`date()` format `nd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (month concatenated to zero-filled day) to remove the year, then you have a 3-4 digit number you can compare that doesn't use the year of the of the dates:

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user)
{
    // Convert to timestamp
    $start_ts = date('nd', strtotime($start_date));
    $end_ts = date('nd', strtotime($end_date));
    $user_ts = date('nd', strtotime($date_from_user));

    // Check that user date is between start & end
    return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
}
```

In fact, you could pass in the format:

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user, $comparator = 'Ymd')
{
    // Convert to timestamp
    $start_ts = date($comparator, strtotime($start_date));
    $end_ts = date($comparator, strtotime($end_date));
    $user_ts = date($comparator, strtotime($date_from_user));

    // Check that user date is between start & end
    return (($user_ts >= $start_ts) && ($user_ts <= $end_ts));
}

check_in_range('2017-05-30', '2017-09-12', '2015-08-06', 'nd') // true
check_in_range('2017-05-30', '2017-09-12', '2015-05-06', 'nd') // false
```

http://codepad.org/Usnxkr9d

Comment: for example, i just need to know if 21 nov is include or not  in the range 1 Nov / 31 jan, without the years...( 21/11 include in 1/11 - 31/01 ?)

Comment: Do it month-day and it sorts correctly, so it can be used to check "betweeness". Both of the functions I include demonstrate that.

Comment: If you were wanting to compare a month and day (and don't know the year), simply add any year to the dates. It ignores them in the comparison, so simply add any recent year (like the current year) to the date string.

Answer (score 0):

You use the PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this. An example using your code:

```
    $start_date = '2009-06-17';
    $end_date = '2009-09-05';
    $x = new DateTime($start_date);
    $y = new DateTime($end_date);
    $dateDifference = $x->diff($y);
    // see difference in days using $dateDifference->d
    // see difference in months using $dateDifference->m
```

Comment: This explicitly does NOT answer the only question, which is how to check by ignoring the year in a date.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not sure why this does not answer the question. I explicitly state how you can see the days and the months difference.

Comment: The question is asking for "how do I check if May 5 is between April 1 and July 31 irrespective of any year in the date".

Comment: for example, i just need to know if 21 nov is include or not  in the range 1 Nov / 31 jan, without the years...( 21/11 include in 1/11 - 31/01 ?)